# AJAX POST Method - Caching JSON Request and JSONResponse

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, caching, post

I have a running AJAX Post Method that 
- takes some text fields data entered, as a JSON request
- gives back rows of data as a JSON response

Now to avoid making multiple requests to server for same input text fields data entered, could I cache the JSON request and corresponding JSON response (maybe like a Key-Value pair kind) in Javascript after I receive my JSON response ? All this as part of the POST method.

Pls let me know, it will be a great help.

Comment: Well the answer is: of course you can. What have you tried so far? You might want to have a look at [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: yeah just put them in JS variables or in localstorage (if they should persist between page reloads)

Comment: I am new to AJAX and was trying to use Cache=true in the AJAX call but that doesn't specify ho request also can be stored. Does the SessionStorage of LocalStorage store JSON Requests also ?

Comment: Ok, so is the below order of tasks correct to do the whole Search program I am building:
1) Keeping SessionStorage in mind, store JSONString for each Search as JSON Objects in the SessionStorage
2) New Search JSONString has to be "deep-compared" to all the JSON Objects from SessionStorage
3) Decide the next steps accordingly, based on (2) above